# Image Parallax in Clickfunnels

Tags: javascript, parallax

I am trying to do an image parallax effect in Clickfunnels, and I am having huge difficulties understanding how to do it.

I do not want background image scrolling, I want individual img to have parallax effect.

I am after this effect

https://www.kyleads.com/conversion-rate-optimization-stats

Clickfunnels is quite different to just using an HTML file for a website. I appreciate any suggestions.